# How to make incremented timer in Core PHP with start pause resume stop button with mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How can we make incremental timer in core PHP. When user click on start button timer will increment by one second and when user will click button that time the timer value stored in database. Then user will resume their work that time timer will automatically start from there when user click on Pause button. Than user will click on stop button the total time of work will stored in database

**Note:** We don't want any kind of plugin pure programming.

Comment: In this case without `javascript` you cant do this, what you want is browser side but storing data to server php is good

Comment: I know that but can u solve this problem.....???????

Comment: This link will helps you do it http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Do you have a music wish on top of your request and how else can we serve your majesty while we're at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two buttons. One `start` another `stop`.

When clicking `start` you make Ajax request to server (since you labeled question as `javascript`).

You have table in database `timer`

```
id | user_id | state | time
```

Ajax request do query to database:

```
 UPDATE timer SET state = 1 WHERE user_id = :user
```

If there is no such entry for current user - add one first:

```
 "INSERT INTO timer (user_id, state, time) VALUES ({$userId}, ".User::STATUS_INACTIVE.", '".time()."')
```

Your Cron job executes query to database every 1 second:

```
 UPDATE timer SET time = time + 1
```

When user clicks `stop` you make another request that updates database and returns current time:

```
 UPDATE timer SET state = 0 WHERE user_id = :user;
 SELECT time FROM timer WHERE user_id = :user;
```

---

As you can see there is no way to execute user commands without javascript.

It would be possible if your user would use CLI.